# Google ml kit: the problem with scanning a barcode with a single number

Tags: android, kotlin, google-mlkit

I'm using Google ML Kit to detect barcodes. I faced the problem that the scanner can not detect a single number represented as a barcode. Is this a bug or a limitation of the Google ML Kit?

Dependense : 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.2.0'

Barcode:

[image]

I have checked several previous versions, but the behavior is the same.

Comment: > I am faced with the problem that the scanner can detect a single number represented as a barcode.     -> You're missing a "not" in this sentence, aren't you?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.